# Valgrind memory leak report differs for executable vs. '.so' library

Tags: memory-leaks, g++, valgrind, shared-libraries

Currently I manage a module of my lab.

I checked for memory leaks using valgrind. I found several memory leaks and fixed them. And when I made a '.so' file to provide the module as a library and test code for running the '.so' library, valgrind reports a memory leak that did not exist in the original program.

There is no missing function in the test code. I think that the difference of options when compiling with g++ cause this situation. But I couldn't verify this.

I use the options below to compile the original module

```
-ggdb -I. -D_DEBUG -D_CICODE -D_EDITMODE -DPOINTER -fPIC
```

and

```
-shared -W1,-soname,libmysutff.so.1
```

to make the .so file.

Working environment: Ubuntu 10.10, g++

This is the output of valgrind:

```
==23426==
==23426== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23426==     in use at exit: 1,148 bytes in 8 blocks
==23426==   total heap usage: 4,294 allocs, 4,286 frees, 43,176,780 bytes allocated
==23426==
==23426== 300 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 5 of 6
==23426==    at 0x4C2815C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==23426==    by 0x400A27: main
==23426==
==23426== 848 (120 direct, 728 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
==23426==    at 0x4C27480: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==23426==    by 0x4E6E6B6: NewPathNode() (mem_manager.cpp:156)
==23426==    by 0x4E61F21: Morph_No_Space(unsigned char*, _path_node**, int, unsigned char) (API.cpp:198)
==23426==    by 0x4E625F6: API_Morph (API.cpp:350)
==23426==    by 0x4E626A0: API_Tagger (API.cpp:379)
==23426==    by 0x400ADC: main
==23426==
==23426== LEAK SUMMARY:
==23426==    definitely lost: 420 bytes in 2 blocks
==23426==    indirectly lost: 728 bytes in 6 blocks
==23426==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23426==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23426==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23426==
==23426== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23426== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: One of the two leaks is __in__ the new test program (`main()`). Compile that with `-g`, too, to see in what line it is. The other memory leak is in the library, but probably did not appear when running the original module because different function calls were made then. Have you checked line 198 of API.cpp to see what is causing the leak?

Comment: try use deleaker. it will show you in which line the leak is.